# Combine number consisting of an overlapping low-part and high-part

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've got measurement data with about 6-7 digits of interested, but since it is logged in a "rough" environment, the data logger is quite primitive (but robust) and can only log 4 digits. Thus I split my measurement data into a low-part and a high part, where depending on the measured quantity up to three digits may overlap, with the values of the low part having precedence.

For example measuring the energy flow in kW:

```
P_real = 34.648  # actual value
P_low = 4.648  # low part
P_high = 34.6  # high part
```

So in this case, to get the "real" energy flow, I need to somehow combine the digits. Since I've got a quite large pandas DataFrame with a shape of more than `(1000000, 150)`, converting to strings and slicing in the correct positions must be avoided.

Furthermore `NaN`s are included in the data. This hampers the integer-conversion and thus additionally requires masking before "combining" the parts.

Some sample data:

```
ser_hi = pd.Series([34.4, np.nan, np.nan, 35.4, 36.5])
ser_lo = pd.Series([4.648, np.nan, 4.698, 5.498, 6.498])
```

Expected output with current "workaround" procedure:

```
mask_nan = ~(ser_hi.isna() | ser_lo.isna())  # mask for non-nan-values
ser_real = pd.Series(index=ser_hi.index)  # create series for masking the result
# workaround calculation with masking to avoid nan-conversion error
ser_real[mask_nan] = (ser_hi[mask_nan] / 10).astype(int) * 10 + ser_lo[mask_nan]
print(ser_real)
# Out: 0    34.648
       1    NaN
       2    NaN
       3    35.498
       4    36.498
       dtype: float64
```

Is there any way to "facilitate" this combination by just "dropping" the digits before/after a specified number of digits? For example as if I combined two strings as follows:

```
str_hi = '34.4'
str_lo = '4.648'
str_real = str_hi[:1] + str_lo
```

But of course for floats, since the performance with strings is terrible. (And even if the performance was ok, I just do not like converting numeric data to strings and back to numeric data. ;) )

Thanks for your advice in advance!

Comment: `ser_real = ser_hi//10 * 10 + ser_lo` should speed things up a bit

Comment: Thanks @Chris, this is working quite well. `np.trunc` seems to be slightly faster for large dataframes.

Comment: interesting, I am clocking it about 100 µs per loop (1000 loops) faster. Good to know.

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'high': np.random.rand(1000000), 'low': np.random.rand(1000000)})` and with setting some nans: `df['high'][np.random.randint(0, 2, 1000000).astype(bool)] = np.nan`, same for low: `df['low'][np.random.randint(0, 2, 1000000).astype(bool)] = np.nan` will yield the following timings: `%timeit df.high//10 * 10 + df.low` 42 ms ± 1.93 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) and `%timeit np.trunc(df.high/10)*10 + df.low` 12.5 ms ± 29.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each). So `np.trunc` seems to be about 3 times faster for a df with 1e6 rows.

Comment: You are correct. Thanks

Comment: Thanks to you for your advice and solution! I'll definetely use it for smaller dfs, since it seems to be faster than `np.trunc` when the df is small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure it answers your question, but using `np.trunc` instead of `astype(int)` should work around the issue with `NaN` data

```
np.trunc(ser_hi / 10) * 10 + ser_lo 

0    34.648
1       NaN
2       NaN
3    35.498
4    36.498
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Great, this quite much looks like what I've been looking for! Thanks alot! With this I can even avoid preallocating the nan-filled columns and masking. :)

Comment: @Scotty1- cool! also floor division, as Chris pointed out in the comment, should work fine. They should be similar performance wise, but it may be worth a test

Comment: Yep, floor division also looks good, I'll also give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

if you choose to cut the signals at decimal points, you can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'high':[34.4, np.nan, np.nan, 35.4, 36.5],
                   'low': [4.648, np.nan, 4.698, 5.498, 6.498]})

# flag the NaN signals
flags = ~df.isna().any(axis=1)

df[flags].high.map(int) + df[flags].low - df[flags].low.map(int)
```

Output:

```
0    34.648
3    35.498
4    36.498
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You may correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't `map` a purely elementwise operation and thus should be avoided performance-wise?

Comment: Indeed, but for 1 million rows, the difference is quite small.

Comment: Yeah, but it is 152 times 1 million rows with more rows coming. :) Furthermore it is slower than my current workaround.

Comment: agreed. Actually, Chris' comment seems to be the fastest, even with `NaN`.